# Transpose R Table

Tags: r

I am trying to transpose a table I have created from a list of lists.
Each nested list has this format:

```
list(storm_name=NA, storm_level=NA, file_date=NA, file_time=NA, 
    date=NA, time=NA, actual_or_forecast=NA, lat=NA, long=NA, max_wind=NA, 
    gusts=NA, eye_speed=NA, eye_location=NA, storm_end=NA)
```

In short, each row has 14 elements within it.

```
storm_df  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(list1), nrow=length(unlist(list1[1]))))
```

The code I have written above so far creates the table where the orientation is 14 rows x N (number of inner lists) columns whereas I would like it to be N rows x 14 columns.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should also look at the `t()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `do.call`, `rbind`, and `lapply`:

```
## data
l1 <- list(storm_name=NA, storm_level=NA, file_date=NA, file_time=NA, 
           date=NA, time=NA, actual_or_forecast=NA, lat=NA, long=NA, max_wind=NA, 
           gusts=NA, eye_speed=NA, eye_location=NA, storm_end=NA)
big_list <- list(l1, l1, l1)

## make data.frame
do.call('rbind', lapply(big_list, data.frame))
```

Stepping through this, first we run `lapply` on `big_list`, so for each item in `big_list`, we create a `data.frame`. Try `data.frame(l1)` to see the result of each call.

Then we use `do.call('rbind', ...)` because the `lapply` returns a lists of `data.frame`s, we want to "stack" the data on top of each other.

Comment: You could also use `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package, which works with lists directly: `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(big_list, data.frame))`.